# Jenkins job not completing even though JBOSS is started

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins job that builds an ear file, deploy it on to a jboss server, and then stops and starts the JBoss server. JBOSS is successfully started but I can still see the progress icon in jenkins console. It just hangs there. If I remove the JBOSS start command, Jenkins build ends fine. Any ideas on what to do with this?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem right now. I am using publish over ssh jenkins plugin to exec my custom made "server_startup.sh" script. And in the jenkins build console log i see "JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started in 43515ms - Started 979 of 1280 services (405 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)" and the jekins job is just hanging waiting for the server to be shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue very similar to yours reading this post

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection

More specifically I did the following in the exec line in publish over ssh

nohup /root/jboss-eap-7.0/startserver.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &